# How can I run Unity 11.04 in qemu?

Tags: unity, 11.04, compiz, virtualization, qemu

I want to try Ubuntu Natty with the Unity Desktop and the Compiz Support from the PPA in qemu. But I can't get the Graphic Support to run Unity.

Is it possible to get compositing running with qemu?

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is: you can't.  Unity requires 3D support, and while it would be technically possible¹ to do this with the software 3D rasteriser, it'll be slow.

As far as I'm aware, qemu doesn't (yet) support virtualised 3D acceleration.  [Virtualbox](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#guestadd-3d) does, as does VMWare.  It should be possible to run Unity in one of those VMs.

¹: mesa's swrast is missing some necessary functionality, so it also requires code to be written before this would work.

Comment: Any recipes on how to see Unity in virtualbox would be appreciated.

Comment: Takkat see my post ...

Answer (score 1):

Great news for those who want to try out the latest Ubuntu 11.04 Natty Narwhal with the Unity interface without booting a CD or Live USB - Unity now works in the latest VirtualBox 4.0

[How To Test Ubuntu 11.04 With Unity In VirtualBox 4.0](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/12/how-to-test-ubuntu-1104-with-unity-in.html)